# Has C# any build configuration manager similar to VC++?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, configuration

I want to configure my project for two different builds (demo and full)

In VC++ I have no problems with that, I can create new configuration like "Release Demo", declare preprocessor directive like `DEMO` and use next code:

```
#ifdef DEMO
   //do something
#endif
```

Then, if I choose this demo configuration at build, I can have even separate folders for "Release Demo" where binaries goes too.

C# has this thing `#if` to mark preprocessor variable dependent parts of code, but which way I can make it build to different folders? Easy declare preprocessor variables for one of configurations only? Etc?

I use VS# Express 2010

[image: my build tab]

Comment: Look at the project configuration dialogs. If I remember correctly, you can define separate compile configs, and deploy rules.

Comment: Not sure if the config is echo´d by preprocessor variables/conditional defines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click on the name of your project in Solution Explorer, then click Properties. Choose the Build tab, where you can see project configurations like Debug, Release. You can set up which one is active, what is the destination folder for a configuration, etc.

Edit: Look at the screenshot

[image]

Edit 2: There's also a way for creating custom build configurations. For that, right click on the name of your solution in Solution Explorer, go to Properties -> Configuration, click on Configuration Manager button (on upper right corner).

Comment: Ehm... i don't see such things in build tab... There is things like "define constant DEBUG", "define constant TRACE"...

Comment: weird... i don't have such things. i updated my question to include screen of this tab

Comment: Probably because he is using the Express edition, I would guess.

Comment: It seems like config manager is disabled by default in Express Visual Studios. Please go to

  Tool -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> General

And check this option there:

  Show advanced build configurations.